# Firebase onMessage is not triggered

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have problems with firebase push notifications. The onMessage event is not triggered

**firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "some_data",
    authDomain: "some_data",
    databaseURL: "some_data",
    projectId: "some_data",
    storageBucket: "some_data",
    messagingSenderId: "some_data",
    appId: "some_data",
    measurementId: "some_data"
});

var messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
     console.log('Message received. ', payload);
 });
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>

<script>
    firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: "some_data",
        authDomain: "some_data",
        databaseURL: "some_data",
        projectId: "some_data",
        storageBucket: "some_data",
        messagingSenderId: "some_data",
        appId: "some_data",
        measurementId: "some_data"
    });

    if ('Notification' in window) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("js/firebase-messaging-sw.js")
        .then((registration) => {
            var messaging = firebase.messaging();
            messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);
            console.log(messaging);
            if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
                subscribe(messaging);
                messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
                     console.log('Message received. ', payload);
                 });
            }

            $('#subscribe').on('click', function () {
                subscribe(messaging);
            });
        });

    }

    function subscribe(messaging) {
        messaging.requestPermission()
            .then(function () {
                messaging.getToken()
                    .then(function (currentToken) {
                        console.log(currentToken);

                        if (currentToken) {
                            sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        setTokenSentToServer(false);
                    });
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.warn('not granted', err);
        });
    }

    function sendTokenToServer(currentToken) {
        if (!isTokenSentToServer(currentToken)) {
            console.log('Отправка токена на сервер...');

            var url = '';
            $.post(url, {
                token: currentToken
            });

            setTokenSentToServer(currentToken);
        }
    }

    function isTokenSentToServer(currentToken) {
        return window.localStorage.getItem('sentFirebaseMessagingToken') == currentToken;
    }

    function setTokenSentToServer(currentToken) {
        window.localStorage.setItem(
            'sentFirebaseMessagingToken',
            currentToken ? currentToken : ''
        );
    }
</script>
```

I'm able to get token and send it to the server. But when I send **request from postman**

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
{
    "notification": {
        "title": "test",
        "body": "test",
        "click_action": "http://localhost:8001/"
    },
    "to": "token"
}
```

I can see nothing on web page, no messages in (response in postman has 200 status)

What is the right way to get notifications from firebase? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you send a `POST` request and verified that you've sent the correct data?

Comment: @Edric - yes, I send the post request and I get the valid response ``{
    "multicast_id": 551265091536786344,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1581072871865893%cc9b4facf9fd7ecd"
        }
    ]
}``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, my postman request was not absolutely right. There are two types of firebase requests, one is for only active browser tabs and second can work in the background. I used the first, that's why I can't see onMessage didn't trigger.

The postman request should be

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
{
    "data": {
        "title": "test",
        "body": "test",
        "click_action": "http://localhost:8001/"
    },
    "to": "token"
}
```

Secondary, before subscribing and sending token to the server, `messaging.usePublicVapidKey()` must be called

And the last one, `messaging.onMessage` also must be before sending token to the server